# How do I segment 3D points?

Tags: python, image-segmentation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onIBK.png)

I want to segment this 3d point cloud to three separate clouds, like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxzEL.png)

The segmentation should work on various models without having to manually fix markers or specify the amount of segmentations that should be done.

Code below for the exact same result as in the pictures:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]]])
data = 1-data
label_array = (label(data, neighbors = 4, connectivity=3))

highval = np.max(label_array)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xs = []
ys = []
zs = []
cs = []

for s in range(highval):
    straw = np.argwhere(label_array==s+1)
    for i in range(len(straw)):
        cs.append(s)
        li = straw[i]
        xs.append(li[0])
        ys.append(li[1])
        zs.append(li[2])
coord_1 = []

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = pd.Series(xs)
df['y'] = pd.Series(ys)
df['z'] = pd.Series(zs)
df['c'] = pd.Series(cs)
print(df)

ax.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], df['z'], c = df['c'],s = 50, cmap = plt.cm.spring)


plt.show()
```

Comment: The term you are looking for is "Clustering": https://towardsdatascience.com/the-5-clustering-algorithms-data-scientists-need-to-know-a36d136ef68

Comment: Yes that was what i am looking for, but the problem is that those methods are depending on manual input in how many clusters there should be. Do you know if there are any algorithm that can segment without having a manual input?

Comment: See this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241381/clustering-methods-that-do-not-require-pre-specifying-the-number-of-clusters